# PHP delete script not functioning

Tags: php, delete-file

I have a script (got it from somewhere here in StackOverflow, credits don't go to me!) to
delete a folder + its contents. However, it's not working for me. After deleting the folder a record from my DB should be erased and this happens just fine. However, the folder doesn't get deleted and neither its contents! This is my code:

```
<?php

$filepath = dirname(__FILE__);
$gemeented = preg_replace( '#^(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$#', "$2", $filepath );
$plaatsd = preg_replace( '#^(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$#', "$4", $filepath );
$hrubriekd = preg_replace( '#^(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$#', "$5", $filepath );
$bedrijfn = preg_replace( '#^(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$#', "$6", $filepath );

$filepath2 = "http://".$gemeented.".url.nl/".$plaatsd."/".$hrubriekd."/".$bedrijfn."/";
$filepath3 = "http://".$gemeented.".url.nl/".$plaatsd."/".$bedrijfn."/";

echo $filepath2;


function Delete($filepath2)
{
    if (is_dir($filepath2) === true)
    {
        $files = array_diff(scandir($filepath2), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            Delete(realpath($filepath2) . '/' . $file);
        }

        return rmdir($filepath2);
    }

    else if (is_file($filepath2) === true)
    {
        return unlink($filepath2);
    }

    return false;
}


?>
```

To make sure my $filepath2 is correct I echoed it, the result is:

```
http://dongen.mydomain.nl/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/bedrijfsnaam/
```

That's exactly the folder I want gone, however, it ain't happening! Folder has CHMOD 755.

EDIT:

Just using $filepath won't work either, echo-ing that gives me:

```
/vhosts/mydomain.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/bedrijfsnaam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the above script working, but I managed to find another script which works for me! Just enter the relative path and that's it!

```
$dirname = "../".$bedrijfn."/";
delete_directory($dirname);

function delete_directory($dirname) {
if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
}
```

Hope it helps somebody out!

Sander

Answer (score 0):

You can't use url to delete files, you should give unlink a filesystem path.
(Edit: the same goes for rmdir)

Comment: That's what I thought! But just using $filepath wouldn't work, that why I created $filepath2. $filepath echo gives me /vhosts/mydomain.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/bedrijfsnaam, so that should work right? It doesn't though..

Comment: Because $filepath contains the parent folder of the file, which you cant delete obviously.

Comment: Not entirely true, the above script seems to do that just fine.